# Correct JSON Feeds context within Drupal

Tags: json, api, drupal, drupal-feeds

I'm trying to access Crunchbase data via their API using JSON, and import into a Drupal site.

I'm using this URL: http://api.crunchbase.com/v/1/company/facebook.js?api_key=tw8xtspmfdsce6q5acwdzwwh

Which I can successfully see the results of at: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

But when I configure the [Feeds JSON Path Parser module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_jsonpath_parser%20%22Feeds%20JSON%20Path%20Parser) what "context" should I use to access the information?

I've tried:

- $
- $.
- $..
- .
- ..
- $*
- $.*
- $..*

But they all return an empty results "context: " - as if no data has been accessed.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

My JSON string lacked any "context" as well. This worked for me...

```
$.[*]
```